# Recovery information from ArcCatalog

Tags: esri-geodatabase, arccatalog

I had a geodatabase file that contained two geodataset, which are line and area. I clicked on the topology to area and then instead of deleting the topology, all the information and edits were deleted from the  ArcCatalog.

Is there any chance to restore my data and files? I lost too many fields and too much information.

Comment: If you delete something, it's deleted.  If this were an enterprise geodatabase, you could go to database backup to recover (provided one was made), but for file geodatabase you're dependent on filesystem backups and personal archives.

Comment: If the file geodatabase was on a network drive and your system is set to restore, try right clicking on the folder in windows file explorer and selecting "restore previous version"?